# Symfony RequestBody swagger annotations not showing schema

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, documentation, openapi

I'm using nelmio/api-doc-bundle v4.9 in Symfony for documentation. Here's the annotation for an endpoint:

```
 * @OA\RequestBody(
 *     required=true,
 *     @OA\JsonContent(
 *     example={
 *      "file": "file",
 *      "documentCategoryCode": "O"
 *     },
 *     @OA\Schema(
 *      type="object",
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="file",
 *          required=true,
 *          type="file",
 *          description="File to be uploaded",
 *          example="file"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="documentCategoryCode",
 *          required=true,
 *          type="string",
 *          description="Document category")
 *      ),
 *     )
 *  )
 * )
```

It shows the example fine:

[image]

However the "Schema" part is an empty object, like the properties are not recognized

[image]

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: Remove the `@OA\Schema(` line and the corresponding closing parenthesis `)`. Does this help?

Comment: @Helen awesome that worked, thanks! Just had to remove "required" property from `@OA\Property` as well and add an object within `JsonContent`, like so: `required={"file", "documentCategoryCode"}`. If you wanna write that as an answer I'd mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 * @OA\RequestBody(
 *     required=true,
 *     @OA\JsonContent(
 *     example={
 *      "file": "file",
 *      "documentCategoryCode": "O"
 *     },
 *     required={"file", "documentCategoryCode"},
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="file",
 *          type="file",
 *          description="File to be uploaded",
 *          example="file"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Property(
 *          property="documentCategoryCode",
 *          type="string",
 *          description="Document category")
 *      )
 *  )
 * )
```

Thanks to @Helen for the suggestion, this was the annotation that worked in the end.